# How to indent all lines of a paragraph by exact distance with ConText

Tags: context

Using ConText I'd like to indent a complete paragraph (all its lines) by a specific distance to the left boarder of the sheet of paper, e.g. 1.7in or 2.3cm and give it a maximum width. I am pretty sure this is a beginner question and I am searching for a way to do it for two days now but for a beginner like me this is really difficult to find.

So it looks like this:

text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text

```
   para para para

   para para para

   para para para
```

text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `narrower`-environment:

```
\setupnarrower[left=2.3cm,right=3cm]

\starttext

text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text

  \startnarrower[left,right]

   para para para

   para para para

   para para para
  
  \stopnarrower

text text text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text

\stoptext
```

[image]